# Why can we crank up the variable $\lambda$ in perturbation theory?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, geometric-series

In the formulation of perturbation theory, we use the power series (more specifically geometric series) for small expansion, say $\lambda$, to expand the exact case, say $H^0$, so $\begin{aligned}
& E_n=E_n^{(0)}+\lambda E_n^{(1)}+\lambda^2 E_n^{(2)}+\cdots \\
& |n\rangle=\left|n^{(0)}\right\rangle+\lambda\left|n^{(1)}\right\rangle+\lambda^2\left|n^{(2)}\right\rangle+\cdots
\end{aligned}$
. Now; later this expansion variable is 'cranked up' to 1. How does the expansion still reflect the exact case of $H^0$
? Is the power series not defined by small $\lambda$
? How do we know if this infinite series converges? Does the infinite series 'imply' that H possesses the necessary properties for convergence?

Comment: Physicists cheat all the time; when it works, it works.

Comment: Griffiths does state that "I'm done with $\lambda$ now - it was just a device to keep track of the different orders - so crank it up to 1", so I guess he just uses the power series to keep track of orders without concerning himself with convergence.

Comment: A full answer (to this good question) would be enormous, instead I recommend [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-3069-2) which will answer all your questions. Briefly: those series (almost) always diverge for all $\lambda\neq0$... nevertheless, the divergent series may be an [asymptotic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion?useskin=vector) which still 'knows' the answer when interpreted in the right way. In some cases it can be proven that this yields the correct answer. In other cases, it's *experimental mathematics* :)